# Unable to fetch value at view.Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to fetch values at view passed from controller.
In my controller my syntax are:

```
public function index()
    {
        $vehicles=vehicles::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
        // return $vehicles;
        $ad=ads::orderBy('views','desc')->get();
        // return $ad;

        foreach ($ad as $ads) {     
            # code...
            $popularvehicle[]=vehicles::where('id',$ads->id)->get();
            // echo $popularvehicle;
        }

        return view('index',compact('vehicles','popularvehicle'));
    }
```

In my views i've tried following:

```
@foreach($popularvehicle as $popularvehicle)
    {{$popularvehicle->vname}}
@endforeach
```

It gives an error of `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$vname`

I've also tried `{!!$popularvehicle['vname']!!}`. But it throws error like undefined index.

When i echo `{!!$popularvehicle!!}` it gives all the values required like `[{"id":3,"vname":"Pulsar","lotno":"Ba 25 Pa","engine":"150","mileage":"35","kilometers":25000,"price":"120000","negotiable":"Yes","vcondition":"New","used":"3 month","manufacture_year":"2015","description":"Almost New","Company_cid":1,"Users_id":1,"Vehicle_Type_id":1,"created_at":"2017-01-12 15:08:41","updated_at":"2017-01-12 15:08:41"}].`

How can i fetch the values of `$popularvehicle`? Can anyone help me? Will converting array to object help solve this problem. If yes, how can i do so?

Comment: It throws following error: Undefined variable: popularvehicle @PunitGajjar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because `->` is trying to point to the property of object `$popularvehicles[]` is an array:

```
 $ads=ads::orderBy('views','desc')->get();
    foreach ($ads as $ad) {
            $popularvehicles[]=vehicles::where('id',$ad->id)->get()->toArray();
    }
```

and then,

```
@foreach($popularvehicles as $popularvehicle)
     @foreach($popularvehicle as $vehicle)
             {{$vehicle['vname']}}
     @endforeach
@endforeach
```

**Note the changes made for naming conventions.** Also, Model name is good to be singular.

Comment: @Anon You adeed `->toArray()` in the query?

Comment: yes.  foreach ($ads as $ad) {
            $popularvehicles[]=vehicles::where('id',$ad->id)->get()->toArray();
    }

Comment: @Anon oh it is `@foreach($popularvehicles as $popularvehicle)

    @foreach($popularvehicle as $vehicle)
    
        {{$vehicle['name'])}}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
` see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider plural name

```
    $popularvehicles = array(); 
    foreach ($ad as $ads) {
        $popularvehicles[]=vehicles::where('id',$ads->id)->get();
    }
    return view('index',compact('vehicles','popularvehicles'));
```

And use in view

```
 @foreach($popularvehicles as $popularvehicle)
    {{$popularvehicle->vname}}
 @endforeach
```

Comment: It gives Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$vname

Comment: did you change `popularvehicle` to `popularvehicles` in controller ?

Comment: Yes `$popularvehicles = array();
     foreach ($ad as $ads) {
      
      # code...
      $popularvehicles[]=vehicles::where('id',$ads->id)->get();
      // echo $popularvehicle;
     }
     
     return view('index',compact('vehicles','popularvehicles'));
    }`

Comment: and did you change in view also ?

Comment: Yes `@foreach($popularvehicles as $popularvehicle)
    {{$popularvehicle->vname}}
 @endforeach`

Comment: change `->get();` to `->first();` inside foreach

Comment: Also are you sure about $ads->id here `where('id',$ads->id)` or it is change something like `$ads->Vehicle_Type_id` or `$ads->Vehicle_id` ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. If it wasn't i dont it would return these values:
`[[{"id":3,"vname":"Pulsar","lotno":"Ba 25 Pa","engine":"150","mileage":"35","kilometers":25000,"price":"120000","negotiable":"Yes","vcondition":"New","used":"3 month","manufacture_year":"2015","description":"Almost New","Company_cid":1,"Users_id":1,"Vehicle_Type_id":1,"created_at":"2017-01-12 15:08:41","updated_at":"2017-01-12 15:08:41"}],`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Controller:

```
$popularvehicle = vehicles::where('id',$ads->id)->get();
// If you use $popularvehicles[] then you have to use one extra foreach() to retrieve the columns
```

View:

```
@foreach($popularvehicle as $vehicle)
             {{$vehicle->id}}    // for id
             {{$vehicle->vname}} // for name
@endforeach
```

Comment: But it would return only value wouldn't it?

Comment: Like earlier, if i dont use [], popularvehicle will only take last value overwriting.

Comment: It only returned 1 value. I have 3 values that should be retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function index()
    {
        $vehicles = vehicles::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
        // return $vehicles;
        $ads = ads::orderBy('views','desc')->get();
        // return $ad;

        foreach ($ads as $ad) {     
            # code...
            $popularvehicles[]=vehicles::find($ad->id);
        }

        return view('index',compact('vehicles','popularvehicles'));
    }
```

And in your view:

```
@foreach($popularvehicles as $popularvehicle)
    {{$popularvehicle->vname}}
@endforeach
```